# Did Minecraft 1.13 change the way iron golems spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have built tango tek's Iron Pheonix iron farm.  Since the update to 1.13, iron golems have been spawning on any open block (except the spawning platform).  They either sit there and block others from spawning, or fall into the ocean below the farm.  Did village mechanics change in the update aquatic change the way that iron golems spawn, and if so, how do I prevent golems from spawning in the wrong location.  Below are some examples of the issue.  [image: golem in the sea]

[image: golems in places they arent supposed to be]

[image: more random places.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 1.13 did have several bugs related to iron farms.

- [Villager detection was changed from 15 to 16 blocks](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-131029)
- [Door detection order was changed](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-134166)
- [Iron golems spawn in the air](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-134889)

The first two are claimed to be fixed by the snapshot 18w30a, but do not use that snapshot since it has a very common game crashing bug. 18w30b seems to be stable however.

Another change that will affect the Iron Phoenix is that villagers swim up water faster, which changed the timing of the water climb from around a minute to 15 seconds. This can be fixed by implementing something to hold the villager from the water column for a while, like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J6WW2FfOhXo&feature=youtu.be&t=12m54s). The rest of the video seems like it can be ignored because of the bug fixes from 18w30a.

I am currently seeing if these fixes work by having my iron farm rebuild itself, but so far it doesn't look too promising because golems are spawning in the air under the eastern and western door pads.

As of 18w31a, the Iron Phoenix works as long as you implement the water column change.

Comment: Let me know if it works, mine were just spawning on the redstone areas on each side, after I blocked those they quit spawning there.

Comment: When I let it run overnight 123 golems spawned which is better than the previous amount that would spawn (several dozen at best), but it's still broken in ways that I don't know how to fix. Most of the golems were spawned outside of the spawning platform too.

Comment: I’ve got 17 golems before the whole thing was even rebuilt. But all of them are in the ocean... hopefully they’ll consider that a bug and fix it

Answer (score -1):

Yes. They've changed a Lot. Lots of farms are now broken.

Your farm has probably suffer a Village update and the villages have become a single Village. Due to this the golems spawning area has moved making the golems to spawn in that location.

If the farm is a self assembling farm, you should press the assembling Button. If it isn't, you Will have to build your farm again.(That's why you should always build self-assembling farms).

I would Also recommend checking for the patch notes and look for the exact changes that have Been Made in the aquatic update.

I hope this information was useful!

Comment: Any chance the newest snapshot will repair them? Or is there any way to fix it

Comment: I've no idea of the content of the next snapshots but 1.13 is a very new version so we still got to wait for a new snapshot. (I edited my answer above so you should read it again.)

Comment: It’s a self rebuilding, the newest snapshot is supposed to fix the golems that spawn outside the center of the village, and also fix the house detection range. But when loaded in this new snapshot, the self rebuilding iron farm produces 0 or very few golems. I think that somehow the villages are merging, even when self-rebuilt.